Why javascript scripts load asynchronously without 'async' keyword?
I'm currently learning how Critical Rendering Path works in web development. Based on what I've read javascript resource should be requested and executed synchronously if there is no 'async' or 'defer' keyword. Yet for me it looks like those scripts are loaded asynchronously:

This is how my HTML looks:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
      integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/5.4.5/typescript.js"
      integrity="sha512-fm/tYhfpqzKSftipRCzM998PwhPuBqaRQJr+CkFtPTZV2BCrVlh2M6ALgXCPvi4SkEqNuzQkF2y4rQkzN/iBew=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.27/vue.cjs.js"
      integrity="sha512-D5aKlu8jWiVzhTlJlx2VVmkThvnXeVQcMjb51kwk2cN4qBbbGfDD61B9M6pwtY5//rJ3v5RWElxj4UPHU1FgdQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-ykZ1QQr0Jy/4ZkvKuqWn4iF3lqPZyij9iRv6sGqLRdTPkY69YX6+7wvVGmsdBbiIfN/8OdsI7HABjvEok6ZopQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.165.0/three.module.js"
      integrity="sha512-Y18NM4/HlOrqWDxpoxC1/TyZkYUvVLe4uxrZXBSXWil6/Ye3XCQecKYWYUmqj8weQcQnblaYxroeGEfAcN5hig=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.7.2/axios.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-JSCFHhKDilTRRXe9ak/FJ28dcpOJxzQaCd3Xg8MyF6XFjODhy/YMCM8HW0TFDckNHWUewW+kfvhin43hKtJxAw=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-chartjs/1.2.0/react-chartjs.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-2kfxqw44S6yapKbmdgSkjIkgOParE7RJfve5OxnbvQC49boT/LXhVvj9h4ILYyKHATf5yPwmv8yQkkXIaeDeLg=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tensorflow/4.20.0/tf.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-p8IRHL1NJ9vHblBMhRwNP1YGLgrbn1QQjcDblL+38ZFtL2GvJHmxxMsAov3q6ujQWKBstrOnprtb+W3hvJPwQw=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body style="background: #222">
    <div>
      <h1>Painted</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

I load scripts without 'async' or 'defer' keyword so I expect them to be fetched and executed synchronously (one after another) yet they are fetched and executed asynchronously, I would like to understand why.

Please replace the screenshots of code with a text-based [mre]

(Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?)

perhaps they are loading in parallel, but being parsed in sequence?

@JaromandaX  it does seem like it if I read this "Main" section accurately https://imgur.com/a/cKMhdEK

but why, why every article on the web says that it should be loaded in sequence

Scripts are loaded asynchronously, but executed sequentially and synchronously. Works as intended.

@woxxom "When the browser loads HTML and comes across a  tag, it can’t continue building the DOM. It must execute the script right now. The same happens for external scripts : the browser must wait for the script to download, execute the downloaded script, and only then can it process the rest of the page." https://javascript.info/script-async-defer , I couldn't find a source that says otherwise

"should be loaded in sequence*" - they are "loaded" in sequence, but are "loaded" in parallel.  It's your definition of "loaded" that is incorrect / too vague.  They are downloaded in parallel and then processed (/parsed) in sequence.     As you're looking at the network tab, you're seeing the download not the parse.

It's like receiving post (snail-mail) - you get a bunch of letters through the letter box, then read them one-by-one.  The browser knows which order to read (process) them, but can receive (download) more than one at a time.

you guys have to be right because I can see your logic in the dev tools, this makes a lot of sense thank you @fdomn and woxxom

However, indeed the specification describes the same outdated behavior, look at that picture down the page. I guess the observed behavior is caused by prefetching which violates the spec or rather it wasn't yet specced.

@woxxom but on https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-script-element.html#attr-script-async it says correctly that async / defer only control execution of the script and not how those scripts are fetched

You look at a draft from 2011.
